# Help installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: installation, server, usb

I'm using an old computer to make a server, it has an Intel CPU and 2GB RAM.

I made a bootable USB flash drive with Universal USB Installer, and even tried with UNetbootin. I am trying to install Ubuntu server 12.04.03 32-bit.

When I boot from the USB flash drive, I first choose the language and then I only get 3 choices, which are: "Test Memory", "Boot from first hard drive", "Rescue broken system".

Why can't I install it on my hard drive?

The hard  drive is formatted and clean.

My desktop is a Compaq from maybe 2008. It has a Pentium dual core processor and *had* Windows Vista, so I doubt there is something wrong with the USB port itself 
because I can easily boot from the USB, but I don't get the option of installing anything to my hard drive, I just get those 3 options that I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another computer you could try a network install i had to do this on my current machine as i had misplaced my memory stick (i then found the memory stick ....irony)

Check this out see if it helps!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server_and_network_installations